# How do I properly implement restarting a multithreaded python application?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a fairly large application consisting of Flask and special software for a fairly complex system managed by a hand written task scheduler. I want to be able to restart my application from the web interface. I'm using Threading, so it follows that I can't force this part of the application to terminate. Some of the tasks can be long, more than 10 minutes. The application uses external resources such as a serial connection to the microcontroller and using a connection to a USB SDR receiver via SoapySDR. It seems to me that using multiprocessing would be quite difficult, due to the use of shared resources. I have little experience with multithreading/multiprocessing programming....

I don't even know which code snippet makes sense to attach.....
Help me please...

I don't have any ideas that I'm sure of

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting your app from a webpage is a bit tricky, but there's a tool called Supervisor that can help. It can start, stop, and restart your app for you with a config file..

sudo apt-get install supervisor

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-manage-supervisor-on-ubuntu-and-debian-vps

It also gives you a webpage to control your app.

Comment: This is not very suitable for me, and I need something cross-platform...